# Spree development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I want to customize [spree](http://spreecommerce.com/). I have downloaded the source files and modified them. Then I ran install.rb which built and installed gems. The question is: can I see the result of the development without gems building, which takes too much time? I'm newbie to RoR.

Answer (score 1):

Customisations to spree are, in almost all cases, better made in your application rather than by modifying spree's source files. The spree developer docs explain how to do so (see in particular the customisation section):

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/